# grunt error: cannot find module 'globule'

Tags: gruntjs

When I run grunt, I am getting the following error message:

```
Aborted due to warnings.
Marios-MacBook-Air:imageResizer mario$ grunt
Loading "watch.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'globule'
Warning: Task "watch" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

The strange thing is that previously running grunt was working and without performing any changes to the file it now returns this error.

Does anyone know what might cause this error and what module `globule` is?

This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "imageResizer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Resize images using GraphicsMagick",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -R html-cov > coverage.html"
  },
  "author": "Mario Mendes",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1.14",
    "gm": "^1.17.0",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "blanket": "^1.1.6",
    "chai": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-execute": "^0.2.2",
    "lodash": "^3.6.0",
    "mocha": "^2.1.0",
    "proxyquire": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

And this is my grunt file

```
var GruntHandler = require("./index.js").GruntHandler;

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        module_target: {
            options: {

                module: true
            },
            files: ['index.js',]
        },

        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['!images/dontdeleteme.png', 'images/*.*']
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-execute');

    var _800px = {
        width: 800,
        destinationPath: "large"
    };

    var _500px = {
        width: 500,
        destinationPath: "medium"
    };

    var _200px = {
        width: 200,
        destinationPath: "small"
    };

    var _45px = {
        width: 45,
        destinationPath: "thumbnail"
    };

    var _sizesArray = [_800px, _500px, _200px, _45px];

    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
        if (action === "delete") {
            console.log("Deleted image");
        }
        GruntHandler(filepath, _sizesArray);
    });



    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);



    grunt.task.exists('watch');
}
```

Comment: can you add the package.json?

Comment: @oliveromahony just added it.

Comment: Your gruntfile probably has `global` misspelled.

Comment: can you add Grunt.JS file ?

Comment: Looks like globule is needed in grunt-contrib-watch, can you see it in the node_modules folder under node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule ?

Comment: @oliveromahony can't find it in the path you specified.

Comment: @santiago-bernabé answer is correct. Seems like you are missing that dependency. Trying doing an npm install and make sure you don't have a NODE_ENV variable set. This should resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some of your grunt-tasks uses `globule` module (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/globule) but it has not specified it in its dependencies. Actually the [grunt API](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt) provide methods to abstract this library, so I guess there is some library deprecated or outdated....

Maybe you are running an old version of one of your grunt dependencies, try executing `npm install` before `grunt`.

Last but not least: if this doesn't work, check your npm cache. Run `npm cache clean` and `npm prune` to clean up your project.

Good luck.